# Cannot find on fly included DOM element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find on fly included DOM element with jQuery.

But it is not working... Any clue?

```
$(function(){
    $("#showDiv").click(function(){
        $.getScript("http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js").done(function(script, textStatus) {
            if (textStatus == "success")
            {
              console.log( textStatus );
              var intervalID = setInterval(function(){
                  console.log("time + 1000" );   
                  if ($('.wrapper').length > 0) {
                      // It is not working... why is it?
                      console.log("It has been detected");
                  }
                  else {
                      console.log("Uppsss");
                  };
            }, 1000);    
         }
        });
    });
    });
```

Comment: what code adds `.wrapper`?

Comment: @lbstr `.wraper` is div that appears when scripts loads content.

Comment: `div that appears when scripts loads content`, from where div appears superman(fun intended) oops @ClarkKent

Comment: The JS script you load doesn't create an element with class `wrapper` (I opened the file and searched for "wrapper"). Probably the script loads other scripts and *those* are creating that element. You are using `setInterval`, so you should detect the elements eventually, *if and only if* the scripts are really creating this element. It kind of looks like they don't though. There is not much we can help you with here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found an answer

```
$(function(){
$("#showDiv").click(function(){
    $.getScript("http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js").done(function(script, textStatus) {
        if (textStatus == "success")
        {
          console.log( textStatus );
          var intervalID = setInterval(function(){
              console.log("time + 1000" );
              if ($('#uploads').contents().find('iframe').contents().find('.wrapper')) {
                  console.log("hello!!!");
              }
              else {
                  console.log("wahaat???");
              };
        }, 1000);

     }
    });
});
});
```